# Not finding my renders

Tags: rendering, settings

I changed all paths in the blender output to the download folder and I hit render
I find there a new .blend file and a new empty folder called blender_evqBBq.
Can anyone figure out where my image render is?

yes I changed the paths in preferences and by the output render settings EVERYTHING

oh and I'm on a Macbook

Comment: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/output/properties/output.html

Comment: Hi. This question is not answerable, since only you know how you set up your render and only you have access to your own computer. Nobody can say for certain even if you rendered any images at all. Also, I don't think this questions meets BSE quality standards. You are supposed to put at least minimal amount of effort to research on your own before asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only the rendered animations will be saved into the folder set in your *Output* panel. For a single image (*Render > Render Image* or <kbd>F12</kbd>), you need to open the *Image Editor* (or use the window that pops up when you render, which is an *Image Editor* window), go into the top bar > *Image > Save As*. Note that the *Image Editor* has several slots, you can temporarily keep several images during your Blender session, but they will be lost as soon as you'll close your file.

[image]

Comment: So thank you very much for this answer because no one tells me that to see a single image you have to save it after the actual rendering... 
and only a video animation will be saved there by itself